# how to activate assert without exception ( as if then else in bash )

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

When I run the following code I get exception, and this is OK because string [0]  is “1” and not 2

So assert make this exception and break from code ….

But what I want to do:

is to print **NOT equal** in case assert string[0] isn’t 1 , and ignore the exception

Else

in case string[0] is 1

then the code will print **equal**

```
  string = "1 2 3"

  assert string[0]          == '2'

  println "continue"
```

.

```
Exception thrown

Assertion failed: 

assert string[0]          == '2'
              |     |            |
              1 2 3 1            false
```

Comment: thanx tim_yates for the update -:)

Comment: Why do you need it from `assert` if you can do the same thing with use of if/else statement?

Comment: because assert is more smarter

Comment: No, it isn't "more smarter". It sounds to me like you shouldn't be using assert for this. It sounds like you are trying to disable the only purpose that assert has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of having as assertion is deviated if you desire to eat the exception on failed Assertion. What you are looking for can be achieved easily by an if/else block as mentioned in the question header.

Just for the sake of verbosity you can add a message to the assertion in either of the below ways, but you would still get an exception on failure:

```
assert string[0] == '2' : 'Not Equal'

// or 
assert string[0] == '2', 'Not Equal'
```

should give a message as

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Not Equal. Expression: (string[0] == 2). 
Values: string = 1 2 3
```

Comment: for example in VB script we have the " resume next" is it possible in groovy :)

Comment: how we can send the assert output to log?